# How to drop rows that: 1)meet a certain criteria and 2) the number of consecutive rows are great?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, if-statement, count

I am trying to set a certain condition and count the consecutive rows that meet this condition and if the count >100. I don't want to drop all of the rows but to keep the first 10 and last 10 rows and delete everything in between (in this case 80 rows). On the other hand, if the count < 100 no rows will  be dropped

```
count = 0

for i in range (len(df.speed)):
   if (df.speed.values [i] <= 15 ):
       count += 1


       if count > 100:
```

sample data and expected outcome

```
i     speed
0       12
1       11 
2       9
.       . 
.       .
120     14
121     18
122     19
123     12
124     10
.       .
.       . 
.       .
180     12
181     19
```

since index from 0 to 120 have a smaller speed than 5, then counter should start from i=0 and stops at i= 120, and since count>100, then the algorithm should keep index from 0 to 9 (10 rows) and i between 111 and 120 (10 rows)and all rows in between should be dropped. Next case, since i= 123 has a speed less than 15, then the counter should start new counting from i=123 and it will stop at i= 180 and since count <100. then no rows should be dropped.

I am mainly stuck in how to delete the rows that are in the middle and to keep the first and last 10 rows. Would appreciate if someone can give a hint. Thanks

Comment: show us some sample data and your expected output

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response. I edited the question and provided some sample data and expected outcome. @Wen-Ben

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a good place for a while loop to collect the DF locs you want to keep. You can merge those locs with the [0:10] and [-10:] positions. Just don't forget to dedup to get rid of any overlap.

Answer (score 0):

I won't give you a complete answer, but two suggestions.

First, to keep track of the last 10 rows, copy all of them to a circular buffer.  You can use a list:

```
final_rows[i % 10] = input
```

If you have more than 10 rows, the last 10 will have been captured in your buffer.  When it comes time to write them out,

```
 i += 1
 for j in range(len(final_rows)):
      output( final_rows[ (i + j) % 10 ] )
```

Second, if you can "back up", you can "delete" output rows after writing them by remembering where the 11th output started, and writing the final 10 rows starting there.  For example:

```
if i == 10: # 11th, starting from 0
   pos = f.tell()
if is_last_row and i > 100:
   f.seek(pos, 0)
   i += 1
   for j in range(len(final_rows)):
      output( final_rows[ (i + j) % 10 ] )
```